# EF Core Grouping

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core

Getting

```json
{
  "Errors": [
    {
      "Message": "The LINQ expression 'DbSet<News>()\n    .OrderByDescending(n => n.DateCreated)\n    .GroupBy(n => n.Category)\n    .SelectMany(group => group\n        .AsQueryable()\n        .Take(4))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.",
      "Description": "An error occured in downstream service. Please contact your system administrator."
    }
  ]
}
```

When

```cs
var groupedNews1 = await newsRepository.GetAll()
    .OrderByDescending(n => n.DateCreated)
    .GroupBy(n => n.Category)
    .SelectMany(group => group.Take(4))
    .ToDictionaryAsync(n => n.Category, n => n);
```

executed.

`GetAll()` returns `dBContext.Set<News>()`;
`Category` is a string

Comment: Which EF Core version? Also try move `OrderByDescending` into `SelectMany` it has no sense before grouping.

Comment: Post the *actual* full exception text returned by `Exception.ToString()`. Although the query is simply invalid in all EF Core versions since EF Core 3.1 and simply can't be translated to SQL. LINQ queries are translated to SQL, and SQL's GROUP BY *reduces* an entire group to a single row. You can't use `SelectMany` with a group.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, this query should work from EF Core 6, or maybe EF Core 7, if they have fixed bugs.

Comment: What bugs? What is this query supposed to do? `GROUP BY` returns only one row per group, so `SelectMany` just doesn't have any meaning. If the intention was to get the first `N` items per group, one could have to use a ranking function with `PARTITITION BY Category ORDER BY DateCreated DESC`. There's no grouping involved at all

Comment: They generate ineffective query with join to grouping again. It is possible.

Comment: dbContext.Set<News>().AsAsyncEnumerable();

Comment: @GHDevOps and what if database has million of rows?

Comment: @GuruStron then use Dapper

Comment: @GHDevOps So your advice from.the start should have been "use dapper")